# what is the matter of this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

it says: $$ \int { \frac{(2+\ln^2x)dx}{x(1-\ln x)}}dx$$

What does that mean? is it writing problem and should be just one dx?

Comment: Someone just forgot that they already wrote the dx part :)

Comment: Strange way to write number $2$ ,....

Comment: it is the way we show number 2 in persian language :)

Answer (score 3):

Someone made a typo. Most likely an extra $dx$. It could also be possible to have two integrals, each deserving its own $dx$, but it doesn't seem like the case

Comment: Ok, but when we have two integrals we write it with one $ \int $ or two $ \int $?

Comment: "It could also be possible to have two integrals" do you mean this form ?$\int { \frac{\int (2+ln^2x))dx}{x(1-lnx)}}dx$ ?

Comment: @Soheil0098 Sure! The typo would be the missing $\int$ symbol. Yes, I'd mean something like what you suggest. But anyway I'd rather stick to my first impression of the "extra $dx$" typo

Comment: ok Thanks, I think so

Comment: NO!  $\int\int f(x) dx dx$ is meaningless.  To have two integrals you must have two variables, like $\int\int f(x, y) dx dy$.

Comment: @user247327 It could make sense when we are talking about indefinite integrals